# Is putting personal projects (in progress or planned) in resume a good thing?

Tags: resume

I'm refreshing my resume to seek for new opportunities as my apprentice contract is about to finish. I'm still a young developer so I don't have many projects to talk about.

So I wonder if putting personal projects that are currently in progress (or being planned) in my resume with some information could be a good thing. I hope to show where I'm developing my skillset, particularly where I don't have professional experience yet.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: Yes specially if the post you want require those technologies.

Comment: Sure, personal projects are still a good indication of your abilities (better, in some cases, as you did the entire project yourself). Github is a good place to put some of the code as well if you wanted to show a potential employer.

Comment: @Walfrat Please refrain from answering in the comments.

Comment: @pay Please refrain from answering in the comments.

Comment: Next time I'll post it as an answer however I feel someone would have commented saying 'don't post a comment as an answer'.

Comment: @lilienthal I'm not really sure about that as "incoming" projects meant that they're not finish or even started for some. And for me it's about the idea of what I'm about to do during my personal time to increase my competences.

Comment: "*they're not finish or even started*" Then they don't belong on your resume.

Comment: @pay Correct. Alternatively you could either flesh out the comment into a full answer (though this is a duplicate so that wouldn't be appreciated either) or opt not to comment instead.

Comment: I disagree that this question is a duplicate, as the OP emphasis is on projects currently in progress or in planning, and so the answer is different to what is in the other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it's a great idea to include those and be prepared to talk about them in any technical interview that follows.  Be sure to be able to translate the skills you demonstrate/learn in those projects to your intended role.

Even though the technologies involved may not be applicable for your day job, your approach and methodology in this development process will be of interest, and it demonstrates your ability to self-govern your work.

It should be pretty clear/obvious to a prospective employer that you'll work on these projects in your own time and that they won't affect your day job (except in a positive way).